# Unable to Decode HTML in WCF Service

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0

```
public string ReturnString()
{
string s = "";
s = HttpUtility.SomeValiable;
return s;
}
```

*SomeValiable* = *<Dependent><DependentId>*

But I am getting the string **s** value like **&ltDependent&gt&ltDependentId&gt**

**NOTE:** I have not applied **;** after **&lt** as it converted it into **<**

Might be the string is not compatible with the HTML format. Please suggest me what datatype I have to use to return HTMLDecode format.

**ANY QUICK HELP PLEASE**

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12642877/prevent-wcf-from-encoding-strings-in-response) question.

The data type you are looking for is  XElement or XmlElement as a return type.

Another easy way that can use string as a return type is to use [System.Net.WebUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to htmlencode before returning in the service and htmldecode in the client.